# How to get json data from Server with jquery mobile?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-mobile, get, jsonp

I am trying to get the Bitcoin course from a web server.

Then we try it with a JSON from local, it works.
In Firebug, I can see the get request to bitcoincharts.com, but there is no answer.

What's wrong with my code?

```
$('#LitecoinMenue').append('<p><b>Litecoin: 42</b></p>');
$.getJSON('http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/weighted_prices.json',
  function(data){
     $.each(data.USD, function(index,item){
       $('#BitcoinMenue').append('<p><b>Bitcoin:'+ item+'</b></p>');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because of a rule called [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). This rule requires that all AJAX requests are made to a file on the same domain name. It is not possible to use `$.getJSON`, or any other AJAX function to load a file from an external domain.

There are only a few options available, the most common is to create a PHP file to act as a proxy, and store it on the same domain. For example:

**proxy.php**

```
<?php
$url = base64_decode($_GET['url']);
return file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

**Your page above**

```
$('#LitecoinMenue').append('<p><b>Litecoin: 42</b></p>');
$.getJSON('proxy.php?url=aHR0cDovL2FwaS5iaXRjb2luY2hhcnRzLmNvbS92MS93ZWlnaHRlZF9wcmljZXMuanNvbg==',
  function(data){
     $.each(data.USD, function(index,item){
     $('#BitcoinMenue').append('<p><b>Bitcoin:'+ item+'</b></p>');
  });
});
```

---

Important Notes:

This is just an example. In a real life situation you would probably want to use cURL to get your file. You should also ensure that it is secured so that someone cannot use Firebug to send an AJAX request to fetch a big file (like a movie) or your server could crash.

As you can see, the URL is base64 encoded. This is to ensure that it gets processed correctly as sometimes there are issues when passing an unencoded URL as a GET parameter. You can encode and decode base64 strings with these online converters: http://base64encode.org and http://base64decode.org, or you can use the built in PHP functions `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()`.

Comment: Hey, tanks for your answer. I am trying to build an jquery mobile/phonegab application. So there is no way to get an external json ? php is not possibile.

Comment: why can i load cat pictures from flicker and a simple json is impossibile ? http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/jQuery.getJSON/index.html

Comment: Flickr uses a policy called [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Relaxing_the_same-origin_policy). This means that when you load the Flickr API URL it sends the Origin request header and Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. Because of this, the browser accepts the request and goes ahead with it.